# Why version format is not x.y.z?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to know the reason why we can't put a version (in project properties) with format "x.y.z" ?

This format is both possible in Android and iOS!

I know that I could put, for example 1.01 in project properties and then edit it in xcode to 1.0.1. But if I retrieve version in my app with `Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppVersion", "1.0")`, it will be "1.01".

Thanks.

Comment: The problem with version numbers is that every OS interprets them a bit differently and you end in conflict. App version is written into the code during cloud build so if you changed it manually that's not something we can see.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Play Store and possible iOS App Store as well don't allow more than one decimal (I'm not sure about the Apple Store, but Apple lets you type in a version number for the store listing also).

Google will multiply the version number you enter in the properties by 100, so using 1.01 (translates to 101) will give you more releases before going to 2.0 than using 1.1 (translates to 110) would. Apple will turn 1.01 into 1.1, but that still gives you 100 releases before going to 2.0 since they don't multiply by 100.

Comment: I'm not sure about "don't allow more than one decimal" fact. Any links ?

I think I'm confusing between marketing version (which appear on store) and developer version ...

Comment: I recall trying it and getting an error message on the Google Developer Console. It's been a while now so I don't remember if iOS was similar but since I try to change as little as possible between platforms I may not have tried it with Apple.

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html
We can set versionName with two decimal (version which appear on play store). 
For iOS, I've compiled yesterday a version "1.0.1" with xCode ...
So, I don't know what to think